# jQuery save state for a div after refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, cookies

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".hide").click(function(){
              $(this).next(".comm").slideToggle("fast");
              return false;
            });
        });
</script>
<div id="com1">
 <button class="hide">Hide/show</button>
  <div class="comm">
    Data here         
  </div>
</div>
<div id="com2">
 <button class="hide">Hide/show</button>
  <div class="comm">
    Data2 here         
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have this code, and i got it to work thanks to stackoverflow answerers, but I have a question about saving the state. I tried a cookie method, but I can't seem to figure out how to save state and load the saved value for each individual div from cookies.

Comment: I tried a cookie method, where I checked wether the div was hidden and saved the value to cookies, but it did not work one bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `class` in place of `id`. Change your **html** like,

```
<div id="com">
    <button class="hide">Hide/show</button>
    <div class="comm">Data here</div>
</div>
<div id="com2">
    <button class="hide">Hide/show</button>
    <div class="comm">Data2 here</div>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/3vW42/)

To save state try to use [localStorage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage && localStorage.getItem('activeComm')){
        comm=localStorage.getItem('activeComm');
        $('#'+comm).slideToggle("fast");
    }
    $(".hide").click(function(){
       $comm=$(this).next(".comm");
       $comm.slideToggle("fast");
       localStorage.setItem('activeComm',$comm.attr('id'));
       return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="com">
    <button class="hide">Hide/show</button>
    <div class="comm" id="comm-1">Data here</div>
</div>
<div id="com2">
    <button class="hide">Hide/show</button>
    <div class="comm" id="comm-2">Data2 here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have it like that in the code - my bad. But I'm wondering how I could save the state after reload, as stated earlier.

Comment: It does work, but still doesn't get the saved state after reload.

Comment: Now check I changed `data('id')` to `attr('id')`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! It's working nicely. I'll try to wrap my head around the syntax of jQuery a bit more in the future.